# Paint App Cannot Send to Local Server

Tags: java, server, client, objectoutputstream

I am writing a Paint App for a CS class and I cannot get it to send data to the server. It is supposed to connect to a server so multiple clients can work on the same painting together but I cannot seem to send the new object to the server. I know it connects to the server because its give feedback on both ends when a connection is established but the ObjectOutputStream.writeObject cannot reach the server. Please let me know what I'm missing! Thanks, everyone!

```
private ArrayList<PaintObject> shapes = new ArrayList<PaintObject>();
private Point startDrag, endDrag;
private ColorShapeSelectorJPanel colorShapeChooserArea = new ColorShapeSelectorJPanel();
private PaintObject currPaintObj = null;
private Socket socket;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private ObjectInputStream ois;

private static final String ADDRESS = "localhost";

public PaintingField() {
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setSize(2000, 1400);
    this.openConnection();
    initializeListeners();

}

// Establish connection with the server.
private void openConnection() {
    /* Our server is on our computer, but make sure to use the same port. */
    try {
        // Connect to the Server
        socket = new Socket(ADDRESS, Server.SERVER_PORT);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Connected to server at " + ADDRESS + ":" + Server.SERVER_PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        this.cleanUpAndQuit("Couldn't connect to the server");
    }

}

// Remove connection with server
private void cleanUpAndQuit(String string) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PaintingField.this, string);
    try {
        if (socket != null)
            socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Couldn't close the socket, we are in deep trouble. Abandon ship.
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

// Get listeners running
private void initializeListeners() {
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        // Begin dragging the shape
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evnt) {
            startDrag = new Point(evnt.getX(), evnt.getY());
            endDrag = startDrag;
            repaint();
        }

        // When mouse is released, get the shape
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evnt) {

            // If rectangle...
            if (colorShapeChooserArea.isRectangleSelected()) {
                currPaintObj = new PaintObject(makeRectangle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, evnt.getX(), evnt.getY()),
                        colorShapeChooserArea.getColor(), false);
            }

            // If ellipse...
            else if (colorShapeChooserArea.isEllipseSelected()) {
                currPaintObj = new PaintObject(makeEllipse(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, evnt.getX(), evnt.getY()),
                        colorShapeChooserArea.getColor(), false);
            }

            // if line
            else if (colorShapeChooserArea.isLineSelected()) {
                currPaintObj = new PaintObject(makeLine(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, evnt.getX(), evnt.getY()),
                        colorShapeChooserArea.getColor(), false);
            }

            // if doge
            else if (colorShapeChooserArea.isImageSelected()) {
                currPaintObj = new PaintObject(makeRectangle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, evnt.getX(), evnt.getY()),
                        Color.WHITE, true);
            }

            // Send the object to the server
            // TODO: FIXME: oos.writeObject NOT SENDING!!!
            try {
                /* Someone pressed enter? Send the message to the server! */
                oos.writeObject(currPaintObj);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                PaintingField.this.cleanUpAndQuit("Couldn't send a message to the server");
            }

            shapes.add(currPaintObj);
            startDrag = null;
            endDrag = null;
            repaint();

        }

    });

    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evnt) {
            endDrag = new Point(evnt.getX(), evnt.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    });

}
```

The problem line is marked "// TODO: FIXME:" The goal has been to notify and send to the server when the mouse is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---- [SOLVED] ----

I had a few problems:

**Firstly**: I had created a **private *ServerListener* class** within the same class which the code above is from BUT I hadn't created an instance of it in the constructor. Dumb. I know.

**Secondly**: The object that I was sending over to the server (*PaintObject*) wasn't serializable. **An object must be serializable to be sent using ObjectOutputStream.writeObject.** The public PaintObject class now begins:

```
public class PaintObject implements Serializable {
```

Those were the issues. I just thought I would be a good internet citizen and answer my own question when I cracked it. I hope this helps some on the future.